# How to convert list to string and how to save for loop result into variable in python?

Tags: python

I need to change this string below to a list, and after that to put every number `**2`. I already converted a string into a list and characters in a string into numbers, but now I need to bring back (`i**2`) numbers into a string without a list. Note that numbers must be again with the type of str. So basically at the end, I need to have string = "9,81,169,16,1764".

```
string = "3,9,13,4,42"

lista = [int(i) for i in string.split(',')]

for i in lista:
   print(i**2)
```

Comment: [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
''.join(list_of_strings)
```

best advise I ever got..

for your case:

```
string = "3,9,13,4,42"

lista = [int(i) for i in string.split(',')]
list_of_strings = []


for i in lista:
   list_of_strings.append(str(i**2))  # appending each value as a string in list 
string = ",".join(list_of_strings)  # the "," will add comma between each values in the list.
```

Comment: Why create a new list?

Comment: Just for demonstration. Part of the OP question

Answer (score -1):

There are probably better solutions but this is what i have:

```
result = ",".join([str(int(i) ** 2) for i in string.split(',')])
```